# Facebook api in actionscript 2.0 examples

Tags: flash, facebook-graph-api, actionscript-2

As i am new to facebook api am trying to implement facebook api in actionscript 2.0 ( connecting to fb sever, user login, highscores submitting ......) can anyone let me know how to implement these things in facebook api in as2. - if possible provide any examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, ActionScript 3.0 is better supported - there's a full-fledged open-source library, for consuming the Graph API with AS3. You'd find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/).

Like Sathish says, consider switching to AS3. While you might find something for AS2 if you dig through [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook%20actionscript%202.0), it's really not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately There is not an official as2 api for Facebook, but googling aggresively I found this: http://www.whiteinteractive.com/facebook/asclient.php

... I don't know anything about this library (plus, the project is discontinued the author himself has abandoned it) so by no means I can recommend it. My advice? Upgrade to as3 and you won't look back, it is so much better (and more powerful) than poor old as2!

Comment: hi sathish,

thank you for the replay,

actually my game is developed in as2.0 so my client need facebook score subimistion and saving the user individual scores.

Answer (score 0):

An option to look at may be to do your facebook integration in javascript, and interface with the javascript using `ExternalInterface`. We are using the javascript SDK rather than the AS3 version for many of our sites.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/